# Plotting symbolic functions

Tags: plotting, symbolic

I want to plot the following Gaussian function

[image]

Is there a way that I can do this symbolically without giving values to the constants.

Comment: Short answer is no, but you could do e.g. a contour plot with x on the  x axis  and b on the y axis?

Comment: Well, you could put $\hat{f} = f/a$ and $\hat{x} = (x - b)/c$, giving the "universal" curve $\hat{f} = \exp(-\hat{x}^2 / 2)$. The three constants just change the vertical scale, the horizontal offset, and the horizontal scale of the curve.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
f[x_, a_, b_, c_] = a PDF[NormalDistribution[b, c], x]
```

[image]

Then

```
ContourPlot3D[f[x, 1, b, c], {x, -3, 3}, {b, -1, 1}, {c, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

Note that I am not claiming it is particularly informative!

This might be more useful?

```
Plot[Table[f[x, 1, b, 1], {b, -1, 1, 1/4}] // Evaluate, {x, -2, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[10]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Table[f[x, 1, 1/2, c], {c, 1/2, 2, 1/4}] // Evaluate, {x, -2, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[10]]
```

[image]